# @Service annotated bean wasn't picked up by SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I used SpringBootApplication in a small project. The architecture is simple:

Entry file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RptApp implements CommandLineRunner 
{ 
  @Autowired private RptService rptService; 
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    rptService.doStuff(){...};
  }
}
```

In which RptService is an interface and it has an implementation: RptServiceImpl.java. It's that the RptServiceImpl.java was annotated with @Service.

```
@Service
public class RptServiceImpl implements RptService {
  @Override
  public void doStuff();
}
```

My understanding is that @SpringBootApplication already embeds @ComponentScan, @EnableComponentScan (or something like that), @Configuration so that rptService should be automatically wired by the container. Rather it threw an error like:

```
Description:

Field RptService in XXXX.RptApp required a bean of type 'xxx.xxx.xxx.RptService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'xxx.xxx.xxx.RptService' in your configuration.
```

I know how to find the workaround basing on the hint, that besides the point though.

I did write another simple class Client and annotate it with @Component and @Autowired it in the main file. Spring didn't have problem picking that up.

The relevant part of my pom file looks like:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
....
```

anyone might shed a light?

Comment: you have class that have method signature only, how did you compile your application in first place?

public void doStuff();

Comment: Is RptApp and RptService in the same package or in different packages?

Comment: What is the project structure of the files?

Comment: @kuhajeyan it's a typo - I've updated the post.

Comment: @Issam EL ATIF you were so right - I was being silly. The RptService wasn't in the main entry file's sub directory. now the problem was resolved.

Comment: what is the package your RptServiceImpl  is in

Comment: @J.E.Y I add it as an anwer It could help someone else

Comment: @Issam EL ATIF - I've accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RptService` should be in the main entry file's sub directory to be picked Spring `@ComponentScan`